# Redirect to URL if specific product is purchased

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone know how to redirect customers to a specific URL, if they buy a specific product?
The product ID is `24251`, and I tried to make it work with the following code (but it does not)

The checkout page url is: `theladybox.dk/checkout-page`

The thank you page url now (for all products is: `theladybox.dk/tak-for-dit-medlemskab`)

Anyone knows where the mistake is?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'checkout-page' ) ) return;


    // Define the product IDs in this array
    $product_ids = array( 24251 ); // or an empty array if not used
    // Define the product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array(24251); // or an empty array if not used
    $redirection = false;

    global $wp;
    $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout-page', '', $wp->request ) ); // Order ID
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object

    // Iterating through order items and finding targeted products
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        if( in_array( $item->get_product_id(), $product_ids ) || has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
            $redirection = true;
            break;
        }
    }


 $url = 'https://mailchi.mp/theladybox/din-ladybox-profil';

    // Make the custom redirection when a targeted product has been found in the order
    if( $redirection ){
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [`woocommerce_payment_successful_result`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/60b385ea93e381fafe092388b27ebfe943a9637a/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L928) filter to change the redirect. You can still use the code you have for detecting if a product is part of the order, but I would probably suggest saving a meta field on the order itself on checkout as that would then be easier to check for here.

```
/**
 * Redirect after order paid.
 *
 * @param string $result - The redirect URL
 * @param int $order_id
 *
 * @return string
 */
function kia_check_for_mnm_edit( $result, $order_id ) {

    // Define the product IDs in this array
    $product_ids = array( 24251 ); // or an empty array if not used

    // Define the product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array(24251); // or an empty array if not used

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object.
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Iterating through order items and finding targeted products
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        if( in_array( $item->get_product_id(), $product_ids ) || has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
            $result = 'https://mailchi.mp/theladybox/din-ladybox-profil';
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;


}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', 'kia_redirect_successful_order', 10, 2 );
```

*Totally untested

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried to use the code and make a test purchase. However, when I try to purchase item 24251 now, it freezes on the checkout page and doesn't redirect at all :( do you know what goes wrong? Br Christina

Comment: Anything in WooCommerce > Status > Logs? Or in the WP_DEBUG_LOG? Sounds like a fatal error... which is highly possibly when I'm cowgirl coding.